# systemStateChanged callback in Unity 2021.1 with ARFoundation 4.1.7 and XR Plugin Management 4.0.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

In the new version there is no UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystemManager, it is replaced by ARSubsystems.
Then How am i supposed to implement the callback of systemStateChanged?
How can i implement systemStateChanged for AR subSystemManager in  ARFoundation scripting. Thank You for the Help.